# Deploy Django api rest in heroku using docker

Tags: python, django, docker, heroku, django-rest-framework

I'm trying to access to my Api rest that I released in Heroku with docker and see that Dynos is running the gunicorn command that I put in the Dockerfile.
The Dockerfile that I used is:

```
FROM ubuntu:18.04

RUN apt update
RUN apt install -y python3 python3-pip
RUN mkdir /opt/app

ENV PYTHONUNBUFFERED 1
ENV LANG C.UTF-8
ENV DEBIAN_FRONTEND=noninteractive 

COPY Ski4All/ /opt/app/
COPY requirements.txt /opt/app/
RUN pip3 install -r /opt/app/requirements.txt
ENV PORT=8000

CMD exec gunicorn Ski4All.wsgi:application — bind 0.0.0.0:$PORT
```

When I release I go into the container via `heroku run bash -a "name app"` and executing `ps aux` I don't see the api running. But if execute the command of my Dockerfile when I'm in the container.

Any idea?

Comment: What exactly do you run when you run it in the docker container?

Comment: Change `RUN mkdir /opt/app` to `WORKDIR /opt/app` and `COPY Ski4All/ /opt/app/` to `COPY Ski4All .`

Comment: @Programmingjoe what do you mean? When I release the container into heroku the CMD gunicorn command should be running once I use heroku container:release -a "app name" or I have to run something after the release?

Comment: @HariHaraSudhan thanks it worked, I guess that the error was that gunicorn was running in  the root path instead of the workdir.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

@jhaos mentioned gunicorn was running in the root path

Change the following in `Dockerfile`

```
RUN mkdir /opt/app to WORKDIR /opt/app
COPY Ski4All/ /opt/app/ to COPY Ski4All .
```

Answer (score 0):

The problem was that the gunicorn command was running in the / root path and not in the correct workdir. In the comments @HariHaraSuhan solved the error.

Comment: You can mark his answer correct below :) I'm sure others will appreciate it as well